# Serializing object in gRPC

Tags: python, json, serialization, protocol-buffers, grpc

I want to send some data (payload) from gRPC server(localhost) to my client (localhost).
I call an API (IMDB -> top 250 movies) and saved my data in a JSON file.
Server response must be the IMDB top 250 movies (As JSON Object)
But I couldn't do that

here is my .proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

// Incoming request from client
message get_top_250_movies{
    optional string name = 1;
}

// Response to be returned by API service
message top_movies{
    optional string response = 1;

}

// Service definition for MoviesData
service MoviesData{

    // get movies method definition 
    rpc get_movies(get_top_250_movies) returns (top_movies) {};
}
```

Client Program:

```
import grpc
import json
import movie_service_pb2 as pb2
import movie_service_pb2_grpc as pb2_grpc



with open('Top250Movies.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)


class FetchMovies:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:50051')
        self.stub = pb2_grpc.MoviesDataStub(self.channel)

    def get_movies(self):
        
        response = self.stub.get_movies(json.dumps(data))
        return response


if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = FetchMovies()
    print(client.get_movies())
```

Server program:

```
import json
from concurrent import futures
import movie_service_pb2 as pb2
import movie_service_pb2_grpc as pb2_grpc



class MoviesDataService(pb2_grpc.MoviesDataServicer):

    def get_movies(self, request, context):

        with open('Top250Movies.json') as f:
            data = json.load(f)

        return pb2.get_top_250_movies(f'{request.name}')


def serve():
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    pb2_grpc.add_MoviesDataServicer_to_server(MoviesDataService(), server)
    server.add_insecure_port("localhost:50051")
    server.start()
    server.wait_for_termination()




if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('running the gRPC server')
    serve()
```

I just need to take any request and send back a response that contains a list of movies that I saved in a json file (Send all 250 movies as a JSON object to client)
json.dumps(pythonObject) will face an error: it couldn't serialized that and expected str | bytes or ...

thanks for your help

Comment: This is not about protocol or framework. In your JSON you have an invalid schema to be Serialized, thats why you are getting the error. There are certain types that are serializables by default, and other that you must give a handler to the specific type.

Comment: actually json file is ok. it's sth like this: {"id":1, "rank": 1, "title":"The shawshank redemption" ...}

Comment: Can you provide the complete error?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. if i send it as a python object (dictionary): TypeError: `'items': [{'rank': '1', 'title': 'The Shawshank Redemption', 'imDbRating': '9.2', 'imDbRatingCount' has type dict, but expected one of: bytes, unicode`  @Jonatrios

Comment: and if i json.dumps(pyDict) error will be:   `debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1647712046.455992056","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:127.0.0.1:50051","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":903,"grpc_message":"Exception calling application: No positional arguments allowed","grpc_status":2}" `   @Jonatrios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was .proto file, I fixed it myself like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";


message MovieRequest {
    // Send a Request to Server
    string movie_list = 1;
}


// this message solved my problem
message MovieList {
    // Get Movie data includes: rank, title, imDbRating, imDbRatingCount
    string rank = 1;
    string title = 2;
    string imDbRating = 3;
    string imDbRatingCount = 4;
}


message MovieResponse {
    // Get a List of MovieList Message; field_name == movies
    repeated MovieList movies = 1;
}

service Movies{
    // Run method get_movies with MovieRequest parameter and return MovieResponse
    rpc get_movies(MovieRequest) returns (MovieResponse);
}
```